# Is a transit visa required for layover in Montreal?

Tags: transit, canada, indian-citizens, montreal

I am a student from India. I have a study permit (temporary resident visa). I was just checking a flight from New Delhi to Toronto. One of the flights I was interested in was New Delhi -> London, London -> Montreal, Montreal -> Toronto.

In Montreal it says I require a transit visa. Do I really need it even though I have a student permit?

Comment: Sorry its not transit visa at the last rather study permit

Comment: You will clear Canadian immigration in Montreal, because that is your port of entry to Canada. You will not clear immigration in Toronto, because the flight from Montreal to Toronto is a domestic flight. Whatever visa or other immigration requirements you have for Canada, then, will be needed in Montreal, not in Toronto. Similarly, as you seem to have realized, because Canada is your final destination, you are not in transit in Canada, and you do not require a transit visa.

Comment: I would answer your question with a proper answer if you clarify a bit.  You say that "it" says you require a transit visa.  What is "it" in that sentence?  Since nobody could possibly need a Canadian transit visa for that itinerary, the claim that one is needed is baffling.

Comment: To be clear - you are studying in Toronto and have a student visa for Canada?

Comment: I did not vote to close this question as a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30522/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-canada; I voted to close it as unclear.  This question is not a duplicate of the other question because the other question is about someone "passing through Canada on my way to somewhere else," which is not the case here.

Comment: @phoog so you want to reopen then close as unclear ? The other answer says "If you don't need a visa to visit Canada, you don't need a visa to transit Canada" which covers the present situation

Comment: @blackbird57 How does that cover the present situation?  In this case, the traveler does need a visa to visit Canada.

Comment: @phoog he's on a student visa, why would he need another visa ?

Comment: @blackbird57: Just because he _has_ the visa that he needs doesn't change the fact that he _needs_ that visa in the first place.

Comment: What @HenningMakholm said.

Answer (score 7):

On the assumption that you are studying in Toronto and therefore have the appropriate visa for Canada **no you do not also need a transit visa to pass through Montreal.**

Transit visas are for when you land in a country en route to a different country. Toronto and Montreal are in the same country.

You will clear Canadian immigration in Montreal, where they will check your visa etc., and then board the domestic flight to Toronto.

Comment: Actually, the answer can be based on a broader assumption: that the traveler has *any* Canadian visa other than a transit visa, since the trip ends in Toronto.

Comment: Also this question is not a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30522/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-canada.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sometimes simple questions like these can halt plans or change flights. This helped a lot.