# Transit visa in the UK and Canada for Libyan citizens

Tags: visas, transit, libyan-citizens

Do Libyan citizens who live in Libya and don't hold any other nationality need transit visas for the UK and Canada? The plan would be to travel on British Airways from Istanbul, Turkey to the Dominican Republic, with stops in the those two countries.

Comment: @pnuts Not a totally worthless question, since it should be pointed out that he doesn't even need a Dominican visa.

Comment: See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30522/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-canada

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=LY&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=do&TR=ca&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by Airlines, you **will** need a visa to change planes in Canada.

As stated on the [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/libya/transit/somewhere_else/no) website, if you change flights in the UK **and** have a valid Canadian visa, you do **not** need a UK transit visa.

Similarly, for the Dominican Republic, also according to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=LY&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=do&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), you can enter on a valid Canadian visa.

So, you **only** need a Canadian transit visa, and no other visas. **No** visa for the UK and **no** visa for the Dominican Republic.

If you're flying back the same way, then, when applying for the Canadian visa, tell them that you need to transit Canada **twice**, so they'll give you the correct visa.

Comment: I would want to double-check that a Canadian transit visa counts for the purposes of issuing a UK transit visa.

Comment: @DJClayworth Double check with whom? The GOV.UK Website clearly says "Rule clearly says "a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used for travel to any country)"