# Do I need visas to travel from Pakistan to Cayman Islands via UK or Canada?

Tags: uk, canada, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am Pakistani and got an approved work permit from the Cayman Islands.

I am planning to travel next week but still confused about connecting flights and visa requirements in connecting flight countries like the UK or Canada (Toronto).

Do I need a visa for traveling through these countries?

Comment: Related (and answers half of your question):  [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Comment: And here's the other half:  [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for Canada?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30522/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-canada)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every country is different. In the UK you would probably need an Direct Airside Transit Visa (https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa), in the US you may need a C1 Transit Visa. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html

It does not only depend on the countries you go through but also on the exact way your flights are booked (single tickets, multiple tickets, layover lengths, etc.)

Trying to get to Georgetown, it's hard to avoid the US or Canada. You could try routing through the Bahamas or Cuba and see if that's easier.

This may be one of the few occasions where a knowledgeable and experienced travel agent would be helpful.