Do i need a transit visa to stay less then 2h in Montreal
I am from Venezuela, I hold a Venezuelan passport. I live in mexico, i will travel to Cancun/ Paris with a layover in montréal for less then 5 hours
How can I submit for a transit visa and  how much it will cost?
Thank you for your answers

Are you transiting through France, through Montréal (in Canada), or both?

What country's passport will you be using?

To make @MichaelSeifert comment question absolutely clear- Montreal the city in Quebec, Canada is not part of France at all and is not part of the Schengen. So if you are transiting through Montreal you are transiting Canada. If your flights go Venezuela to Montreal (Canada) to France to Singapore, you are transiting both Canada and separately France. Please make it clear in your question, and also your citizenship.

What did the official website say when you checked it to Find out if you need a visa to travel to Canada?

Can you clarify your itinerary? My understanding is you want to fly France -> Montreal -> Singapore which doesn't make much sense, especially as there are no direct flights from Montreal to Singapore (and it would be quite a detour). Please give the point of origin, the destination, and the connection airports. Also please tell us if all the flights are on a single ticket or are booked separately, as well as any visas or residence permits you may hold.

Please edit your question to provide the necessary details: what passport you hold, what visas and permits you hold, where you are starting from, where you are going to, and what airports you will go through on the way.

It said that I need a transit visa. Some sites said it is free some asked me to pay 100$

It will be Paris/ Singapore. then my connection flight is a a Montréal layover 1h 50 min

@MehdiHamsi Apply through the official website, a transit visa is free. Also check the processing timescale, which could be months. Why are you not taking a flight from Paris to Singapore? A detour vis Canada makes little sense, and if Canadian Immigration suspects your motives for such a detour are not genuine, it could mean your application gets refused.

See also: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30522/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-canada

@MehdiHamsi Your itinerary does not make any sense. There are no Montreal-Singapore flights, and flying from Cancun to Paris to Montreal to Singapore is probably the largest detour ever. Also, are all your flights on a single ticket? If not, which flights are on which tickets?

If you're in Paris, you want to go to Singapore, but you head towards Montréal, you're going the wrong way

While the itinerary makes no sense: If both flights are on the same ticket, then you need a transit visa. If the flights are on separate tickets, while for Canada a transit visa would be fine, the airline is very likely to require a visitor visa (they will consider Canada to be your final destination, and need proof you can enter Canada before they will let you board). If you have checked luggage or for any other reason need to go to the check-in desk then it is a hard requirement. But if you show that itinerary to any visa officers they will be extremely suspicious of your intentions.

You changed the itinerary in your question to remove Singapore, and it's now unclear when you plan to stop in Montreal? Is that between Cancun and Paris? That makes a bit more sense, but please confirm that this is the case, and quite importantly, whether the two flights are on the same ticket or booked separately.

Canada provides a handy website to see if you will need a visa or other document for your travel.
In your case, you have to apply for a transit visa, which is free of cost as mentioned in the website.
Start here:
https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit.html

While helpful this does not answer the question. You can rescue this by running the information known about OP through that site and coming back with the best guess.

I think that the further comments with the OP unfortunately don't provide more clarity about the necessary facts.  Regardless, the website /workflow is tremendously useful for anyone
